# Collection for many elements and multithreaded reading

Tags: java, collections, threadpoolexecutor

There is a task in which it is necessary to subtract from the database a huge list of models (several millions) and, based on the data of each model, make separate calculations and save them in another database.

Faced with the problem of creating the storage of a set of models in order to take data from there in multithreading mode. How best to implement this so that the threads generated by the Executor receive data from the collection of models without repetition. In this case, does the thread need to pick up the object and delete it in the collection? It sounds anti-productive.

I don't really understand which collection to choose so that it works correctly and as quickly as possible.
And how to prevent the same object from being used several times by different threads without deleting it. The option to divide in advance into subcollections is not suitable, because models can be processed at different speeds.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is too broad, IMHO... can you add more details like code you've tried already? See [ask].

Comment: It’s strange that you want to make calculations using data you just deleted it in the database. Unless you are actually describing two unrelated tasks.